# Display Charts based on year select in django

Tags: python, django, database, select, chart.js

I am using django=3.0.0 as my backend. I have years in my database as a datetimefield and I want to put it as an option for my select button which will change the charts dynamically in chartjs.
Do I have to make a filter for this or is there any other way to put my years in chartjs.
Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65706671/edit) your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's an example.

```
# views.py

class SomeView(View):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      context = {} # put some data here
      return render(request, "pathto/jsfile.js", context)
```

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
   # ...
   path("chart/js", views.SomeView.as_view(), name="js"),
   # ...
]
```

```
# template
<!-- example -->
<div>
   <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'js' %}"></script>
<div/>
```

```
# jsfile.js

var chart = document.getElementById("chart");

{% if some_context %}
   // do something 
{% endif %}
```